# Why does my MSWord not show the checkboxes in my Word Document when I'm using the Wingdings font?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, printing

When I print to PDF, and when I print to my printer directly, the bullet points don't show up. The text that correspond to the bullets show up -- but the bullets themselves don't. For the bullets, I'm using a custom font (Wingdings) and the square character. That way I can make a todo list with check boxes =) But they are not appearing!

Comment: The printer driver does not recognise the custom font. Try using the drawing objects instead.

Comment: Uh just use the box bullet type then customise the bullet formatting to have a large box?

Comment: @Randolph: how can I get my printer driver to recognize the custom font? I'm using a Canon Pixma printer, the MP280.

Comment: @Todda, not really sure what you're saying. In order to get the large box, I used the Wingdings font. Is there another font I should choose instead [that is likely more compatible with my printer]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the document to an image. Then print it out.

Comment: How do I save the document to an image?

Comment: @ZacharyBurt just to clarify - does the document look perfectly fine in PDF?